# Facebook App id rejected with .me domains?

Tags: facebook, app-id

Hello I've just tried to get app id for a .me domain, and it gives an error:

```
Error
You have specified an App Domain but have not specified a valid integration URL.
o-star.me must be derived from one of: Site URL, Mobile Site URL, Canvas URL, Secure Canvas URL, Page Tab URL or Secure Page Tab URL.
```

Thanks